# Why does the mesh get deleted when parenting to the generated rigify rig?

Tags: rigify

I adjusted the bones in the rigify add on and they fit my mesh, then I generated it and it still matched up well, and when I parented it with automatic weights, it goes from a full human to what's shown in the image.[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Hi Nolan, can you post a .blend?

Comment: Did you *apply scale* to your model before parenting to the rig? (Ctrl + A)

Comment: @MikeBelanger I didn't parent the rigify to the mesh yet. The original bones are in the second layer. Check it out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrMQl4A3FTwRUxmVTRsbm1xZTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You called it Timaroberts.  The scale of metarig (I'm assuming that's the master rig) was bigger than metarig.001, which I assume is the slave rig.  So all I did was scale metarig.001/apply metarig.001 to metarig's, applied the scale to both armatures/mesh, and then changed your mesh's armature settings to point to metarig.001.  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40846